# rspec with format and drb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I can't get rspec to run with --format option AND --drb, is there a way to make this work?

I am running rspec spec --format documentation --drb

and get the error

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

if I run rspec spec --format documentation

it runs fine

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace of the error

Answer (score 0):

I've had success with `$ rspec --drb --format documentation spec/`.